# Spring restTemplate .postForObject() mapping cannot access element

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

Im trying to use the restTemplate.postForObject(URL, Session.class) method and map the response to a POJO. This works partially, however when i try to access an element with a name like "name-with-dashes" I cannot find the element.

The JSON I am extracting from the method call:

```
{"age":60,"expire":12345,"name-with-dashes":"This name has dashes?!"...}
```

Here is the POJO im using to extract this data:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Session {
        private int age;
        private long expire;
        //will not grab name-with-dashes... returns null
        private String nameWithDashes;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should annotate your fields, especially the ones that do not comply to bean naming conventions, with the [@JsonProperty](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/latest/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) annotation as follows:

```
@JsonProperty("name-with-dashes")
private String nameWithDashes;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can annotate the property

```
@SerializedName("name-with-dashes")
private String nameWithDashes;
```

using Gson